# Non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, identifier, literals, non-ascii-characters

I'm getting an error as '*Non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers*'. Below is code :

```
- (void)purchaseMyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

    if ([self canMakePurchases]) {
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Purchases are disabled in your device" message:nil delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

I'm getting this error on *else block*. I have tried deleting empty spaces but didn't worked. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with that code.

Comment: Clean your build. Product->clean

Comment: Also try `View > Text > Show Control Characters` to see if something strange is in the source file.

Comment: @Nikita : I have tried 'Clean' approach but didn't work

Comment: Try deleting the line with the `else` on it (delete it completely, including the line break), then type it in again.

Comment: Have you tried accepting the Fix-it that Xcode is offering?

Comment: Repeating what @KenThomases said: That should be the obvious solution, and unlike many others, it actually works. Xcode doesn't only tell you what the problem is, it even suggests to fix it for you. Learn how to use your tools.

Comment: @gnasher729 the fix-its for these things don't always work — Xcode isn't particularly bug-free. I'm assuming OP tried this before asking, though maybe I'm being too optimistic...

Comment: @KenThomases : I tried Fix-it but didn't work. But I got a fix for this. Below I have posted answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the line with the `else` on it (delete it completely, including the line break), then type it in again, manually, then clean and build again.

Xcode sometimes mishandles the way spaces are inserted when you copy and paste code from a rich-text source (e.g. a website), and unicode spaces are inserted instead of normal spaces, and these are not recognised by the compiler. Deleting the line completely and retyping it manually solves this problem as the offending characters are removed.

Comment: There is no "mishandling" here. When I copy text I expect it to be pasted in as it is, and that's what Xcode does.

Comment: @gnasher729 I say "mishandling" because I have had instances where the spaces were in fact normal, non-Unicode spaces, and Xcode did this. If you disagree with my wording, feel free to edit.

Comment: @gnasher729 : Use of "mishandling" is appropriate in this context